# Does record type with key exist in F#

Tags: f#, record, key-value

In OPL (Optimization Programming Language), we have a data structure name [tuple](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_datatypes_tuples.html). OPL tuple correspond to Record in F#. Here is how it is defined:

```
tuple Point {
       int x;
       int y;
    };
```

Like in F#, we can access field by using dot notation

```
int x = p.x;
```

We can group tuples in a Set:

```
{Point} points = {<1,2>, <2,3>};
```

A difference is that like in database systems, tuple structures can be associated with keys. Tuple keys enable to access data organized in tuples using a set of unique identifiers. In the following example, the nurse tuple is declared with the key name of type string.

```
tuple nurse {
  key string name;
  int seniority;
  int qualification;
  int payRate;
}
{ nurse } nurses = …;
```

The nice thing about key, is that we can initialize an array this way

```
int NumberOfChild [n in nurses] = 0;
```

and accessing a value by using only the key:

```
NumberOfChild[<"Isabelle">]=20;
```

leaving out the fields with no keys. This is equivalent to:

```
NumberOfChild[<"Isabelle",3,1,16>]=20;
```

Also, using key means that there will be no two tuples with the same key. Like primary key in database.

**Question is**: Does some type like this exist in F#? Record with key?

**My goal**: I would like to define a node structure with many attribute. And load a graph structure by only giving the key of the node and not the entire Record since I would load the graph from a database.

```
type Node = {
    nodeKey : int;
    nodeName : string;
    nodeAttribute1 : string;
    nodeAttribute2 : string }

let Graph = [
    (1, 2);
    (1, 3); 
    (2, 4);
    (3, 4) ]
```

Where the int in the graph tuple represent `nodeKey`.
I would like to do operation using the graph but accessing the node information using the key only.

[OPL Grammar](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/opl_grammar.html)

Comment: Why not use a Map or Dictionary?

Comment: F# can make use of .NET library, which has [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) and F# modules which have [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-class-%5bfsharp%5d)

Comment: You are right, I can us a map to do the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no such language-level concept. All record fields are created equal, so to speak.

That doesn't preclude you from:

1. synthesizing a key for a record based on one or more field values,
2. using such a key as a key in a `Map` that would hold your records or any additional values.

So you can have something like this:

```
type Nurse = { name: string; seniority: int; qualification: int; payRate: int }

let nurses = [ { name = "Isabelle"; seniority = 3; qualification = 1; payRate = 16 } ]

let numberOfChildren = 
    [ "Isabelle", 20 ]
    |> Map.ofSeq

let nursesWithNumberOfChildren = 
    [ for nurse in nurses do 
        match numberOfChildren |> Map.tryFind nurse.name with
        | Some children -> yield nurse, children
        | None -> yield nurse, 0 ]
```

Using similar approach you can separate your graph and node data - store only keys in the graph and maintain a mapping that goes from keys to full node records.

Answer (score 1):

```
//If I read data from a database, I would receive the data in the following form:

type XYZ = {X:int;
            Y:string;
            Z:float} 

let recordsXYZ = [{X=1;Y="A";Z=1.0};{X=2;Y="b";Z=1.0};{X=3;Y="A";Z=1.0}]

//I can create a map this way
let mapXYZ1=recordsXYZ|>Seq.groupBy (fun a ->a.X)|>Map.ofSeq
//But I don't want a Map<int,seq<XYZ>>
//This is what I want
let mapXYZ2=recordsXYZ|>Seq.map (fun a -> (a.X,{X=a.X;Y=a.Y;Z=a.Z}))|>Map.ofSeq

//Or maybe this is cleaner but this need to define another type
type YZ = {Y:string;
            Z:float}
let mapXYZ3=recordsXYZ|>Seq.map (fun a -> (a.X,{Y=a.Y;Z=a.Z}))|>Map.ofSeq
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your best bet is simply a cleaner alternative to `Seq.groupBy` for your purposes. Here is the core of it, in one line:

```
let inline project projection value = projection value, value
```

Given a simple helper function, not specific to `XYZ`

```
let projectToMap projection values = values |> Seq.map (project projection) |> Map.ofSeq
```

it becomes trivial to cleanly create maps of `XYZ` from any "key":

```
let mappedByX  = xyzs |> projectToMap (fun { X=x }      -> x)    // Map<int, XYZ>
let mappedByY  = xyzs |> projectToMap (fun { Y=y }      -> y)    // Map<string, XYZ>
let mappedByZY = xyzs |> projectToMap (fun { Y=y; Z=z } -> z, y) // Map<float*string, XYZ>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/TQE8Sw)</kbd>